# Apache2 - virtual host domain routing issue

Tags: apache2, ssl, routing

I am trying to set up multiple websites on a single Ubuntu 16.04 installation, and so far have installed Ubuntu with LAMP and SSL (Letsencrypt).

My issue is that the first domain ( website1.com ) points to the right folder ( var/www/html/website1 ), but my second domain ( website2.com) points to the first ( var/www/html/website1 ).

I have created /etc/apache2/sites-available/website1.conf and 
/etc/apache2/sites-available/website2.conf files and configured as follows:

**Website1:**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c><VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
ServerName website1.com
ServerAlias www.website1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website1 
<Directory /> 
    Options FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride None 
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/website1> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow,deny 
    allow from all
</Directory> 
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/website2.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/website2.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**Website2:**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c><VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
ServerName website2.com
ServerAlias www.website2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website2
<Directory /> 
    Options FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride None 
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/website2> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow,deny 
    allow from all
</Directory> 
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/website2.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/website2.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I have a2ensite website1.conf and a2ensite website2.conf
I have a2dissite 000-default.conf and default-ssl.conf
I have also tried a2ensite default-ssl.conf

I have restarted (sudo systemctl restart apache2) after each change.

Many thanks for your ideas in advance!